# Azure Logic Apps Custom connector that returns image/png content type cannot be written to Blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I created a custom connector using an OpenAPI specification for an API here:

https://api.cloudmersive.com/image/docs/v1/swagger

Then I am making an Azure Logic Apps flow that uses the Face cropping function to crop images in a Storage Account one at a time and then output the cropped images back to the storage account:

[image]

So here is the problem: in the "Blob Content" field for Create Blob (which is intended to write the output back to the storage account), it will not let me select the output of my custom connector, even though the OAS spec for that function is to return "image/png".

Is this a bug, somehow, in Azure Logic Apps?  Do I need to convert the output from my custom connector into file content?  If so, how do I do that (I couldn't find a "Convert" connector)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the connector specifications [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/) , it specifies that the Blob Content should be a binary type. So you could try applying the @binary() or @base64() to the output of your custom connector.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to define the Custom Connector to have binary output?  Currently the OpenAPI 2.0 specification already says that the output is a file.

Comment: Hi @Abr. Did you find an asnwer to this question?

Comment: @Victor I didn't get a good answer actually; still hoping someone from Microsoft will respond

Comment: @Steven Van Eycken the problem here is that I shouldn't have to say @binary() the system should just know that it is binary.  What OpenAPI specification properties do I need to set to get this to work??